# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - Not able to work with XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, updates, visual-studio-2015

Installed VS2015 Update 1 and facing a load of issues!

What I have tried till now:

- Removed the ComponentModelCache and restarted. Did not help.
- Repaired VS 2015 and it did not help (XAML lost outlining)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2015 (XAML is no longer displaying)

Error message(s):

1. Project could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.
2. Intellisense could not be initialized due to the following error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Metadata.ManagedTypeResolverService..ctor(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Package.XamlLanguagePackage.b__10_3(IServiceContainer c, Type t)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Package.XamlLanguagePackage.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.GetFileContextScope(String fileName, IVsTextLines textLines, IXamlFileInformationContext& fileContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.CreateSource(IVsTextLines textLines)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: I solved it by copying the folder "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" from my colleague. I am not sure if this will bring more issues with it in the future.